# How do I want to store the condition value in variable in selenium ide

Tags: selenium-ide

I have a application which contains first page..

The navigation of the flow is

If it is a first login:  Page A --> Page B --> Page C

For subsequent login:  Page A --> Page C

Here my condition is I will check some of the text in Page B using verifyTextPresent. If yes, I will do some operation to go to Page C and then i will do my activities in Page C. If no, I will do the activity directly in Page C.

I need to verify the text by VerifyTextPresent and if exists i set a value true to any variable and then the second step i will variable is true or false and then i will proceed.

How to attain this? also if you have any other idea also would be fine for me...

Thanks in advance..
Chandra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found this is working

storeTextPresent| text which you want to check |x